# For loop prints different output Can this be checked please

Tags: python, for-loop, capitalize

I'm really frustrated how the for loop works. Ill post two scenarios. My output should be
"12 abc"-->"12 Abc" and if "12abc"-->"12abc"(output). But I came up with two solutions for this:

```
s= '12 abc'
a_string = s.split()
for word in a_string:
    print(" ".join(word.capitalize()))
```

If i use this for loop I'm getting output as
"1 2
A b c"

**Another solution*
print(' '.join(word.capitalize() for word in a_string))

If I use this for loop I'm getting the correct solution as "12 Abc"

But,

```
for word in a_string:
        print("".join(word.capitalize()),end=' ')
```

The above code prints a space at the last. I also don't want that extra space also.

Comment: `word.capitalize()` is a string. When you pass a string to `" ".join()`, it will be treated as a "list of characters". So you are basically doing `" ".join(["1", "2"])` etc.

Comment: print(' '.join(word.capitalize() for word in a_string)) --- The same is done here too. But this gives the correct output. word here also refers to string. Please explain

Comment: That's because `word.capitalize() for word in a_string` is not a string. It is a "generator" (which is kind of like a list). You need to realised that you were passing a string to `join`. That is the source of your frustration. When you pass a string to a function that expects a list, the string will be treated as a "list of characters".

Comment: Yes I almost got it, Can you please say how word.capitalize() for word in a_string and for word in a_string:
    print(" ".join(word.capitalize())) differs you are saying the first one is a generator but the second one you are saying its a string. How did you recognize that it is a generator

Comment: See my updated answer. I recognize that form as a generator (it is used a lot in python). It always looks liks this: `f(x) for x in list_of_x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s= '12 abc'
a_string = s.split()
capitalized_strings = []
for word in a_string:
    capitalized_strings.append(word.capitalize())

print(" ".join(capitalized_strings))
```

Notice that I am putting the capitalized words into a list and then using `join` with this list.

Your problem is that you were passing a string to `join`. This treats the string as a list of characters.
So you are basically doing `" ".join(["1", "2"])`

An explanation of generators:

When you write

```
word.capitalize() for word in a_string
```

it returns something called a `generator`. A generator is "iterable" like a list.

For example, if you did this (where `a_string` is a list of strings):

```
a_string = ["12", "abc"]
list_of_words = [word.capitalize() for word in a_string]
print(list_of_words)
```

then you would get this:

```
["12", "Abc"]
```

That is called a "list comprehension".

So when you write:

```
" ".join(word.capitalize() for word in a_string)
```

it gives the same result as if you did this:

```
" ".join(["12", "Abc"])
```

So `join` will join the 2 elements in that list, with a " " space between them.

This is different to calling:

```
" ".join("Abc")
```

If you pass a string to `join`, it is the same as if you did this:

```
" ".join(["A", "b", "c"])
```

because the string gets interpreted as a "list of characters".

Use this code to see everything printed as it is calculated step-by-step:

```
s = "12 abc"
print(s)

s_list = s.split()
print(s_list)

s_capitalized_list = [x.capitalize() for x in s_list]
print(s_capitalized_list)

result = " ".join(s_capitalized_list)
print(result)
```

Notice that I used `x` in my generator in the list comprehension. This is to show you that the name you choose does not matter.

Comment: But can you please explain how join treats it as a character but this one is same too but this one gives the correct answer  print(' '.join(word.capitalize() for word in a_string))

Comment: I have added a lot of explanation to my answer. I hope it becomes clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "123 abc"
result = s.title() if ' ' in s else s
print(result) # "123 Abc"

# try changing the s to "123abc" and see the result
```

Try this one. This is a bit more pythonic.

Comment: I think this is not exactly what is required. For example, consider `s="123 123abc". That should output "123 123abc" but your approach would output "123 123Abc"

Comment: True. Maybe we could split the string on whitespace and then use `title()` to the substring which doesn't have any number? @Peaceful James

Answer (score 0):

There is a module in python called re(Regular expression),which makes us to solve these type of answers . Try out this code:

```
import re
    x="12 abc"
    m=""
    for i in x:
        if i.isalpha():
            m=i
            break
    m=m.upper()
    q=re.sub(" [a-z]",m,x,1)
    print(q)
```